# sbt update is not resolving the latest artifacts from repository

Tags: scala, build, sbt

My project has few snapshot dependencies in the `build.sbt` file like this:

```
Seq("com.asr.project.myproject.urproject" %% "asr-app" % "0.0.0+")
```

I am executing `sbt update` to get the latest dependencies.

Prior to this, I have recently published artifacts with latest SNAPSHOT versions for few dependencies.
By the definition `sbt update` should have checked for the latest dependencies versions on the repository but it doesn't seem to be working like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbt` uses coursier plugin to manage the dependency tree and the coursier plugin maintains the lifetime of the artifacts in the cache.
When a dependency is downloaded, it is not going to be checked for any updates for next 24 hours(Default).

This behavior can be altered by setting `COURSIER_TTL` as an environment variable (e.g `export COURSIER_TTL=0s`). Running `sbt update` alone will not have any effect without it. https://get-coursier.io/docs/ttl

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.asr.project.myproject.urproject" %% "asr-app" % "0.0.+"
)
```

as described in [Ivy revisions](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Ivy+revisions), or at [Fixed and dynamic revisions](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision) with more details.